# CakePHP 2.0 says that email is invalid

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a Component that I use to send off emails in CakePHP 2.0. It was working perfectly up until I put the site on a live host. Now, I get the error:

> Invalid email: "admin@website.com"

Obviously, the above email address is valid, so I don't know why Cake is throwing an Exception here. Note that I get the same result, regardless of what email address I use.

Component function that I use:

```
public function send($to, $subject, $body = null, $view = 'default', $vars = array(), $layout = 'layout'){
    try{
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->config('default'); 
        $Email->template($view, $layout)->viewVars($vars);
        $Email->from(array(Configure::read('Site.email') => Configure::read('Site.name')));
        $Email->to($to);
        $Email->subject($subject);

        if(strlen(trim($body)) > 0){
            $Email->send($body);
        } else{
            $Email->send();
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e);
    }

}
```

In my email config file, I'm using the default Mail transport.

Update: I seem to be having the exact same issue as the [person in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429079/adaptive-client-manager-error-when-sending-email). Basically, I'm getting the error:

> Invalid email: "email@website.com" 
>   An Internal Error has occured.

Comment: `admin@website.com` is the email stored in `$to` or `Configure::read('Site.email')` variable?

Comment: @ArunJain admin@website.com is stored in `Configure::read('Site.email');` I've manually added different email addresses, to no avail. I even commented out the `CakeEmail::from` call, only to be given an exception for the `CakeEmail::to` call, which was myname@hotmail.com

Comment: If the problem trickles to the `to` line when the `from` is commented out, then I would suspect it happens earlier. Comment out the template line and see if the code works error free.

Comment: @AgRizzo I commented out the template and also the config call, just to see what would happen. Still getting an invalid error on the from email. Starting to think this could be host-related.

Comment: Sounds like it's most probably a value that you've set in your email configuration. Have you checked the stack trace to figure out from where this actually stems? Are you using a custom [**email pattern**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#CakeEmail::emailPattern)? Have you checked whether the internally used `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` successfully validates the address? ... ps, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version!

Comment: Also once you've found the value make sure that no invisible control chars have slipped in.

Comment: @ndm No custom pattern and I've made sure that there are no special characters. Worked on my localhost, but doesn't work on the production server.

Comment: Well, there's not much more anyone can do from here other than guessing. So I'd say you'll have to do some more debugging on your end, as already suggested check the stacktrace and figure where exactly the exception is thrown (most probably caused by the result of the already mentioned `filter_var()` call), isolate that code and test it outside of CakePHP and see if it behaves differently on your servers, and if it does, try to find the cause by conforming the environments to each other until they both work or both fail.

Comment: @ndm I've updated my question with a link to another question where the OP seems to be having the exact same issue. He has included a stack trace in his answer.

Comment: The only thing that is of interest is the stacktrace of _your_ error that occurs in _your_ environment! No offense, but having to worm proper details out of somebody with 10k+ rep feels kinda ridiculous, I mean, you still haven't even mentioned your exact CakePHP version, nor any other environment details that would maybe allow someone to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My apologies. I guess I should explain that I only have access to the code base at certain times. I'll get a stack trace up in a bit.

Comment: Facepalm... see my answer. I messed up on a config value and it seems to have broken Cake's error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I feel a bit silly now:

Basically, I realized that I didn't set the content type in my email config. On my local machine, I'm using Google's email server to send HTML emails. On the production server, I was using the regular Mail configuration. Unfortunately, I forgot to set the content type for this particular type of mail (whereas it was set for the Gmail config). The issue here is that many of my layout & view files for HTML emails didn't exist for textual-based emails. This seems to have broken Cake in some form or another, leading it to dump out nonsensical errors about emails being invalid, even though they were.

To be honest, I stumbled upon this by accident. Yesterday, I uploaded some code to try and debug the issue. To my surprise, my test code worked. It then dawned on me that in my test code, I was ***manually*** specifying default views and layouts. i.e. I wasn't using any of my custom views.

To test my theory out, I made sure that the HTML views and layouts also existed for textual-based emails. Sure enough, my emails began to send.

Since then, I've set the content type to HTML and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas

```
$Email->to(Sanitize::paranoid($to, array('@'));
```

Also, make sure the ->to() function is actually setting $to to ->to :)

Otherwise, set it up like this:

```
$Email->to = Sanitize::paranoid($to, array('@');
```